# #Frida #Android - Is there a way to read arbitrary arguments of a native method intercepted by Interceptor.attach() -> onEnter(args) method

Tags: android, frida, native-methods

Let's say I have a native method which address is `expfunction.address`. I tried to intercept the function call and get its arguments, general idea:

```js
Interceptor.attach(expfunction.address, {
    onEnter(args) {
        console.log("\n-----\n[*] Function is called!);
        for(let i in args) {    
            ... read value of args[i] ...
        }
        
    },
    onLeave(retval) {
        console.log("\t\n-----\n[*] Function returns");
        console.log("\t[+] Returns:", retval);
    }
})
```

The function's arguments can be any datatype such as `jboolean`, `jstring`, `jobject`, etc. So how to get exactly the datatype of `args[i]` and properly read the value of it.

By the way, Is `for(let i in args) { ... }` a correct way to enumerate `args` array? Since trying to get `args.length` raises `RangeError: invalid array index`.

What I have tried so far (and they all return blank):

- Failed 1

  ```js
  onEnter(args) {
    for(let i in args) {    
          var tmp = new NativePointer(args[i]);
          console.log(tmp.readPointer());
      }     
  }
  ```
- Failed 2

  ```js
  function getType(value) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).toLowerCase();
  }
  ...
  onEnter(args) {
    for(let i in args) {    
          var tmp = new NativePointer(args[i]);
          console.log("Type:", getType(tmp));
      }     
  }
  ```

Thank you for reading to this point :)

Comment: First I am not sure if frida really known how many arguments a native function has. The common way I use is to decompile the method id IDA Pro or Ghidra and only use the number of arguments shown in the decompiler. If you want to get the type follow the variable where it is used and if it is a method with known parameter or return type you have the type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Robert. I'm writing frida code to find any native function in any module that match a regex, then hook all of them and get their arguments. That's why I'm looking for a generic way to do so, but there're likely none

Comment: This will only work if the method is a JNA method which also has a method definition on Java side where you can get the arguments and their type. Or if the `.so` file is not stripped and thus contains debug information. But I don't know what is all included in such a debug info and if it is accessible in Frida. Besides that I agree with you that there is no generic approach. On native level you just have a register or stack value but if it is a boolean, a value or a pointer is only defined by the code that uses it.

Comment: just to make sure: you know [`frida-trace`](https://frida.re/docs/frida-trace/)? Up to a certain degree it does exactly what  you have outlined in your question (hooking methods based on regex).